# Data reflects in InnoDB table after 3 minutes

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions, innodb, myisam

Issue:
1. Insert query is executed using a node application
2. SQL query is seen in RDS logs
3. But, data is not reflecting on **select query**. Data is seen in table after exact 3 minutes.

**Note**: This issue doesn't happen if I change the Table engine to MYISAM.
Also, doesnt happen if I fire the insert query through Mysql-terminal

Any idea? How to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you commit your first transaction only after 3 minutes. Not sure how or why you commit late (usually, if you forget a commit and the transaction times out/you close it, the default behaviour would be to rollback), but maybe this gives you a starting point for what to look for in your code. Maybe try to enable autocommit (if you do not need or have explicit transactions).

Comment: @Solarflare is correct. Does your code disable autocommit with a SQL statement like `SET autocommit = 0;` somewhere? If you want more help please [edit] your question to show the INSERT code.

Comment: Fixed.. @Solarflare You were right. Commit was missed in a procedure which was called before to this insert query.

Comment: My rule:  Never use `autocommit = OFF`; you will forget to `COMMIT`.  Always pair up `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`, and do them in the same subroutine so that it is obvious that they are still paired up.